# failure to execute expect in bash script

Tags: terminal, cron, debian, expect, sudo

I have written an bash monitoring script containing expect for automatic login to vpn services.

There are only root and User1 on the system.
It works as expected when executed by sudo from terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
vpn_user=$(getent passwd | grep "/home" | tail -1 | cut -d":" -f1)

write_log(){
    echo "$msg" >> "some.log"
}

log_to_vpn(){
/usr/bin/expect -c '
    set timeout 10
    spawn sudo -u "User1" nordvpn login
    expect "Please enter your login details.\r" {
        expect "Email / Username: " { send "User1@mail.com\r" }
        sleep 1
        expect "*assword*" { send "User1Password\r" }
        interact }
    '
}

if ( sudo -u "$vpn_user" nordvpn account | grep "Active" ); then
    msg="INFO: $vpn_user is already logged to VPN."
else
    msg="WARNING: Logging to VPN by $(whoami) as $vpn_user."
    log_to_vpn
    sleep 1
    if ( sudo -u "$vpn_user" nordvpn account | grep "Active" ); then
        msg="OK: Logging to VPN as $vpn_user has been successful."
    fi
fi
write_log
```

When executed from terminal messages are: *"INFO: User1 is already logged to VPN."* or *"OK: Logging to VPN as User1 has been successful."* depending on situation if User1 is already logged in or not.

The problem is it doesn't do the job when executed as crone job.
In this case some.log has got only entries *"WARNING: Logging to VPN by root as User1."*

Why does it not work?

Comment: cron runs with a very minimal path. Make sure nordvpn can be found in the PATH used by cron.

Comment: @glenn jackman: thank you for your comment. In terms of adding nordvpn path to crone I'd rather keep it inside script for clarity. Few releases back nordvpn didn't allow su to do anything, now this is available again but i kept "sudo -u" just in case.

Comment: @pynexj: thanks for hint. This script is the only application of expect on my system. Installing sexpect wouldn't be excused.

Answer (score 0):

Expect's interact works only when stdin is on a tty/pty but cron job is not running on tty/pty.

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.

log_to_vpn(){
/usr/bin/expect '
    set timeout 10
    spawn sudo -u "User1" nordvpn login
    expect "Please enter your login details.\r" {
        expect "Email / Username: " { send "User1@mail.com\r" }
        sleep 1
        expect "*assword*" { send "User1Password\r" }
        # interact }- to replace with below:
        send "exit\r"
        }
        expect eof
    '
}

.
.
```

Problem solved :)